# What is this while loop doing?

Tags: php

So I've been doing some math trying to use this loop for my project and I cannot understand no matter how hard I try why does this loop run two times instead of one.

```
$currValue = 40.3;
$maxValue = 40.6;

while ($currValue < $maxValue) {
  $maxValue = $maxValue - 0.3;
  echo $maxValue . '<br>';
}

// Output:
// 40.3
// 40.0
```

I would be really grateful if somebody provided me with some sort of explanation on this and or a way to work around this. I hope this question isn't a duplicate, I didn't manage to find anything similliar.

Comment: @JohnBupit I think you're on the right track, the logic works fine with integers.

Answer (score 1):

Run this it should demonstrate what the problems is. Its related to IEEE floating point representations being slightly inaccurate for some numbers.

```
<?php
$currValue = 40.3;
$maxValue = 40.6;

while ($currValue <= $maxValue) {
  $maxValue = $maxValue - 0.3;
  echo 'maxValue -  ' . number_format($maxValue, 20) . ' currValue = ' . number_format($currValue,20) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Best to look at something clever that I am https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. Its a mine field for sure!

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

```
 $currValue = 40.3;
 $maxValue = 40.6;



 while (round( $currValue, 1) < round($maxValue,1)) {

  $maxValue = $maxValue - 0.3;
  echo $maxValue . '<br>';
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer further?

Comment: while executing the code in question the loop was executing one more time. This was because of representation floating point numbers. Therefore I have rounded of these numbers before comparing them thereby having a range for precision check while comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Use rounded value in the loop like

```
round($maxValue,1)
```

instead of

```
$maxValue
```